# Start systemd service from Ansible Playbook

Tags: systemd, aws, ansible, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

> **What specific syntax must be used to get an Ansible playbook to successfully start a systemd service and make sure that the systemd service is running on an Amazon EC2 instance?**

**CURRENT SYNTAX:**

The following syntax in an Ansible Playbook passes as successful when the playbook is run, but then we find that the `myapp.service` is subsequently not running when we putty into the EC2 instance to examine:

```
- name: create the myapp service file.
  shell:
    cmd: |
      cat << 'EOF' >> /usr/lib/systemd/system/myapp.service
      [Unit]
      Description=myapp service
      After=syslog.target
      After=network.target
      [Service]
      User=myapp-host
      Type=simple
      ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'cd /home/myapp-host/myapp-files/ && /home/myapp-host/bin/bundle exec myapp serve --source /home/myapp-host/myapp-files/'
      Restart=always
      StandardOutput=syslog
      StandardError=syslog
      SyslogIdentifier=myapp
      [Install] 
      WantedBy=multi-user.target
      EOF
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  become: true
  become_user: root
  vars:
    ansible_become_password: "{{ root_pass_myapp }}"

- name: Make sure myapp service is running
  systemd:
    state: started
    name: myapp
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  vars:
    ansible_become_password: "{{ root_pass_myapp }}"
```

**FAILED CURRENT RESULTS:**

Next, when we putty into the EC2 instance, we get the following results from `systemctl status myapp.service` :

```
[myapp-host@ip-12-3-4-56 ~]$ sudo systemctl status myapp.service
● myapp.service - myapp service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/myapp.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Wed 2020-10-21 22:33:25 UTC; 2min 10s ago
  Process: 19716 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c cd /home/myapp-host/myapp-files/ && /home/myapp-host/bin/bundle exec myapp serve --source /home/myapp-host/myapp-files/ (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 19716 (code=exited, status=127)

Oct 21 22:33:25 ip-12-3-4-56.aws-region-n.compute.internal systemd[1]: myapp.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Oct 21 22:33:25 ip-12-3-4-56.aws-region-n.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit myapp.service entered failed state.
Oct 21 22:33:25 ip-12-3-4-56.aws-region-n.compute.internal systemd[1]: myapp.service failed.
Oct 21 22:33:25 ip-12-3-4-56.aws-region-n.compute.internal systemd[1]: myapp.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 21 22:33:25 ip-12-3-4-56.aws-region-n.compute.internal systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for myapp.service
Oct 21 22:33:25 ip-12-3-4-56.aws-region-n.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start myapp service.
Oct 21 22:33:25 ip-12-3-4-56.aws-region-n.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit myapp.service entered failed state.
Oct 21 22:33:25 ip-12-3-4-56.aws-region-n.compute.internal systemd[1]: myapp.service failed.
[myapp-host@ip-12-3-4-56 ~]$
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why Ansible reports the service as started. However, you should start by checking the service on the EC2 end first. If you manually run `sudo systemctl start myapp.service`, do you see the same error? If so, you can investigate further with `journalctl`. (1/2)

Comment: Going one step further, I'm guessing that you're running a Ruby app (based on the bundle exec serve syntax). In that case, [this QA from ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/984291/349846) may be helpful. It looks like a possible issue with paths and/or environment variables. (2/2)

Comment: Can we take this to chat? I've [created new room here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115420/jekyll-as-a-systemd-service).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was very simple.  Just add `source /etc/profile` to the `ExecStart` command as follows to resolve the error:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'source /etc/profile && cd /home/myapp-host/myapp-files/ && /home/myapp-host/bin/bundle exec myapp serve --source /home/myapp-host/myapp-files/'
```